# How to use binding property as a function parameter in C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Maybe I missed the lesson about this, who knows...

This is the regular binding:

```
var picture = new Label();
picture.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Picture"));
```

But, I want to use the value that is sent as "Picture" as a function parameter, for example:

```
LoadImageFromUrl("ValueOfPicturePropertyHere");
```

I will use the value of `LoadImageFromUrl("ValueOfPicturePropertyHere")` as an imageSource later on this project.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Picture property by using the binding context and then pass it to the Method you want.

```
var context = this.BindingContext;
LoadImageFromUrl(context.Picture);
```

the idea is that if you are binding a property on your view model you can easily get the latest value of it on code behind using the sample i provided

Comment: I get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Picture'... I ended up using a converter... However, your code would have been better. However, I have another project that will work better with similar code as yours. Any help on this error?

Comment: Solved that by casting BindingContext to the right class. Thanks